# Trying to plot histogram - overwritting values

Tags: python, histogram, telegram, overwrite

I'm trying to plot the histogram from list in Telegram bot. I use for it 'finallist', after loop I clear my all list, but it seems that histogram takes all values from previous inputs and plot new histogram with all of them, only changing colors:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import time
import telepot
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import logging
import os

x = list()
l = list()

def handle(msg):
    content_type, chat_type, chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)
    print(content_type, chat_type, chat_id)
    print("Hi, start typing!")

    if content_type == 'text':
        if msg['text'] == 'clean':
            x.clear()
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Your list is empty. ')
        else:
            if msg['text'] == 'histogram':
                finallist = l[0]
                i=1
                while i < len(l):
                    finallist = finallist + l[i]
                    i = i+1
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Here is the list of occuring numbers:' + str(finallist).strip(' '))
                fig = pl.hist(finallist)
                plt.savefig('finalplot.png')
                bot.sendPhoto(chat_id=chat_id, photo=open('finalplot.png', 'rb'))
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'This is your histogram.')
                x.clear()
                finallist.clear()
                l.clear()
                os.remove("finalplot.png")
            else:
                x.append(msg['text'])
                l.append([int(i) for i in str(msg['text'])])
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Your list is: ' + str(x).strip(' ') + str(l).strip(' '))


TOKEN = 'mytoken'  # get token from command-line

bot = telepot.Bot(TOKEN)
MessageLoop(bot, handle).run_as_thread()
print('Listening ...')

# Keep the program running.
while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Can you show the content of l[0] in python?

Comment: I set up l=list() at the beggining of function, then if user is providing the number list l collects this number as a list:
l.append([int(i) for i in str(msg['text'])])

Comment: Please, print it and post the exact value here.

Comment: Also, what is `pl`? I suppose you imported it like `import matplotlib.pyplot as pl`

Comment: I've just updated it adding whole code. It is working for me, as long as I'm not trying to clear all lists (which is done after histogram) and starting adding new ones.